# How radio button click if included onclick function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, webbrowser-control

```
<asp: label input name="id" value="p" onclick="form.submit(); 
      return false;" type="radio">personal / romance 
/label>
```

I am trying below both code but not getting any solution. Please if anyone have any good solution then it's really good help for me.

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id").SetAttribute("value", "P");

foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("label"))
{
   if (el.InnerText == ("personal romance"))
   {
       el.InvokeMember("Click");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks okay, but the `InnerText` of the label is not **personal romance**

Try it like this:

```
string searchString = @"personal / romance";
if(el.InnerText.Equals(searchString)
{
    el.InvokeMember("click");
}
```

Check when expect this element if the correct tag name is `label`. I can tell you for sure that this is not `asp:label`. You can check with `Inspect Elements` in `Chrome`, if the tag name is different use correct one when you are taking `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName(correct tag)`

Comment: @SherazulSumon I don't understand what do you mean by red mark.

Comment: I am getting following error when puting this code Error 1 The name 'el' does not exist in the current

Comment: @SherazulSumon this code should be in your foreach insteal of current if.